# hibernate jpa spring mvc example validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am working on a POC project which has JPA, Spring MVC with hibernate. In that I just wanted to do validation for each form (jsp) I use. I am using hibernate entity object directly into my controller , this stops me to do validation. Any idea how do I use validation for each page (i.e, form) ?

Comment: Have you tried using spring MVC Form validation API ? Check http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation

Comment: You can use filter in your `web.xml` file. [http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial]

Comment: I have found an example , need to have domain object which will be same as entity object and need to iterate the domain object and set it into entity object. Is this way correct?